# VBA to click image placed in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba, excel

I have been trying to write excel VBA  code that clicks on an image that has been placed in an HTML Table.  The image which I am trying to click has only the source code.

I Tried in 4 different ways to click the image, but none of these worked.  Can anyone please help me how to write VBA code?

1.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Dim ElementCol As Object
Set ElementCol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each link In ElementCol
    If link.innerHTML = "excel.jpg" Then
        link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next link
```

2.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Dim i As Object
For Each i In HTMLDoc.images
    If i.src = "../images/excel.jpg" Then
        i.Click
    Exit for
    End If
Next i
```

3.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Dim img As Object
For Each img In HTMLDoc.all
    If img.innerHTML = "excel.jpg" Then
        img.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next img
```

4.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Set HTMLDoc = site.document

Dim tdCollection As Object
Set tdCollection = HTMLDoc.all
    For Each cell In tdCollection
        If cell.ID = "singleXLS" Then
            cell.Click
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

Here is the HTML code.

```
    <tbody><tr>

<td id="singleXLS" onclick="javascript:gCognosViewer.getRV().viewReport('spreadsheetML');" return="" true;"="" style="cursor:hand;" valign="middle" align="center"> 
<img src="../images/excel.jpg" border="0"></td> 

<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

As suggested, here is the code I am using.

```
Sub click_img()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Set site = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    URL = Range("B2").Value  'There is an URL in cell B2

    site.navigate URL
    site.Visible = True

    While site.busy
        Wend
    Do Until site.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop


    Set HTMLDoc = site.Document
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("singleXLS").getElementsByTagName("img")(0).Click 'Error is here
End Sub
```

Comment: HTMLDoc.getElementbyId("singleXLS").getElementsbyTagName("img")(0).click

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Tim.  I tried this. But I am getting Run-time error 424: Object Required.   Could you please help.

Comment: the code I posted should work given the HTML you supplied.  Would be helpful of you could post your current code.

Comment: I have pasted the code that I am using (last section).  Please check and suggest if something needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Set HTMLDoc = site.Document
HTMLDoc.getElementById("singleXLS").getElementsByTagName("img")(0).Click
```

Try:

```
Dim s, i

Set HTMLDoc = site.Document
Set s = HTMLDoc.getElementById("singleXLS")
If Not s Is Nothing Then
    Set i = s.getElementsByTagName("img")(0)
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        i.Click
    Else      
        Debug.Print "Img not found!" 
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print "singleXLX not found!"
End If
```

A lot more code, but it will help you pin down the exact problem

Comment: Thanks Tim....   Now I am getting Run-time error 13 : Type Mismatch in line :  Set s = HTMLDoc.getElementById("singleXLS").  I have been trying to execute this code since many days, but I could not as I am getting different error every time.  Is there any other way to click the images (eg., fireevent Onlcick)?

Comment: Without a URL to test it's difficult to know what the problem is. Are you using my code exactly as posted?

Comment: Sorry Tim,  sharing url will not help as it needs user id and pw to log on.  And sharing it will be a violation.   Yes,  i used the code exactly as posted. Still getting error.  Don't know what's wrong with my Excel VBA..

Comment: I realize you can't share the URL - just pointing out that without that it's very difficult to make any more useful suggestions